# Asking reviews about the designed circuit On topic or Off topic.?

Tags: discussion

I recently designed a board layout in Eagle and was thinking to post question so that anyone can review it and verify it as I am a beginner.
This type of questions are ON topic or OFF topic on Electronics stackexchange. If they are ON topics where can I upload schematics or board layout. ?

Comment: Also http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/399/107479 and http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3803/107479

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A general review of a complex circuit would have to be classified as "too broad".

However, if you have specific questions about some particular aspect of your design that could be answered in a few paragraphs, that would be perfectly acceptable.